# javascript - `<form>` and `</form>` in same line .Other elements generated outside form

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a form using javascript ,and subsequently adding the elements.
This code runs onclick event of a button .
But the generated code contains the `<form>` and `</form>` code in single line and the elements generated after this line.
I have given inline style border  to the form.
  The form border  covers only one line and the controls are generated outside the form.

How to bring all elements between the `<form>` and `</form>`  ?
A portion of my code below.

```
    var f_id = frm_main_id + "_set" + (set_no + 1);
    var criterias_csv_id = frm_main_id + '_criteria_csv';
    var criterias_csv = document.getElementById(criterias_csv_id).value
    var criteria_array = criterias_csv.split("|");
    var fldno = 0;
    var i;
    var fid = "activity" + act_no + "_time_" + (set_no + 1) + "time";        
    var x = document.getElementById("id_" + act_no + "_fieldset")

    var f = document.createElement("form");
    f.setAttribute('method', "post");
    f.setAttribute('id', f_id);
    f.setAttribute('action', "submit_criteria.php");
    f.style.borderStyle = "solid";
    x.appendChild(f);

    //var table = document.getElementById("id_" + act_no + "_table");
    var new_table = document.createElement("TABLE");
    new_table.setAttribute('class', "class_open");
    new_table.setAttribute('form', f_id);
    new_table.style.borderStyle = "solid";
    x.appendChild(new_table);
    var new_row = document.createElement("TR");
    new_table.appendChild(new_row);
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    new_row.appendChild(th);
    th.innerHTML = "Observed Time" + (set_no + 1);
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    new_row.appendChild(th);
    var s = document.createElement("input");
    s.setAttribute('type', "datetime-local");
    s.setAttribute('id', fid);
    s.setAttribute('form', f_id);
    s.setAttribute('required', true);
    th.appendChild(s);
    for (i = 0; i < criteria_array.length; i += 2) {
        fldno++;
        fid = "activity" + act_no + "_time_" + (set_no + 1) + "_criteria_" + fldno;
        var new_row = document.createElement("TR");
        new_table.appendChild(new_row);
        if (i == 0) {}
        var field_type = "";
        var fldname = criteria_array[i];
        field_type = criteria_array[i + 1];
        field_type = field_type.trim();
        switch (field_type) {
            case "Numeric":
                field_type = "number";
                break;
            case "TEXT":
                field_type = "text";
                break;
        }
        var new_row = document.createElement("TR");
        new_table.appendChild(new_row);
        new_col = document.createElement("td");
        new_row.appendChild(new_col);
        new_col1 = document.createElement("td");
        new_row.appendChild(new_col1);
        new_label = document.createElement("label");
        new_label.setAttribute("for", fid);
        new_label.innerHTML = fldno + ")" + fldname;
        new_col.appendChild(new_label);
        switch (field_type) {
            case "number":
            case "text":
                var s = document.createElement("input");
                s.setAttribute('type', field_type);
                s.setAttribute('id', fid);
                s.setAttribute('required', true);
                s.setAttribute('form', f_id);
                new_col1.appendChild(s);
                break;
            case "YN":
                var s = document.createElement("SELECT");
                s.setAttribute('id', fid);
                s.setAttribute('form', f_id);
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = "";
                option.value = "";
                s.add(option);
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = "No";
                option.value = "N";
                s.add(option);
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = "Yes";
                option.value = "Y";
                s.add(option);
                new_col1.appendChild(s);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    new_row = document.createElement("TR");
    new_table.appendChild(new_row);
    new_col = document.createElement("td");
    new_row.appendChild(new_col);
    s = document.createElement("input"); //input element, Submit button
    s.setAttribute('type', "submit");
    s.setAttribute('value', "Save");
    s.setAttribute('form', f_id);
    s.setAttribute('onclick', "x()");
    //"clk_save(', $act_no, ',', $edit, ')"> 
    new_col.append(s);
    new_col = document.createElement("td");
    new_row.appendChild(new_col);
    new_col.append(s);
}
```

I currently set the form attribute of each element separately and it works fine. But the border around the form is only for the first line.
Any idea??

Comment: Could you please create a runable snippet that illustrates the example. Cut it down to the bare minimum that illustrates the problem.

Comment: What elements do you want to put in the form? Why are the `id_X_fieldset` elements created without forms in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestions.
 I have posted the full code.
I did following correction and everything is fine

x.appendChild(new_table); replaced x. with f.